# Calculate element padding dynamically using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, math

I'm trying to calculate the padding-bottom property for multiple elements in an image gallery. Check out the following code for one element:

```
<div class="item-container fashion">
    <a href="images/fashion/11-large.jpg"
        data-size="600x900"
        class="item"
        style="padding-bottom: 150%">
        <img class="lazyload"
            alt="Description"
            src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAAAAACH5BAEKAAEALAAAAAABAAEAAAICTAEAOw=="
            data-sizes="auto"
            data-src="images/fashion/11-small.jpg"/>
    </a>
</div>
```

As you can see I define the size of the image in **"data-size"** attribute (600x900). In order to get the padding-bottom value which I need to prevent reflow, I simply divide calculate (height/width) x 100, which in this case yields 150 - my padding-bottom value.

Now I can easily calculate this manually and input it as I'm doing above and it works just fine. But since my gallery will contain hundreds of images all with different ratios, I'm gonna need a more automated way of calculating the padding value.

Is there anyway to achieve this by doing the calculation in JavaScript and then apply it to the respective element? If I were to include the dimensions in the filename for example and parse it maybe I could even avoid manually inputting the data-size value too...?

I would really like to avoid having to manually do hundreds of calculations, plus It'll be great to learn a new trick for the future. Thanks!

**UPDATE**

here's what I got so far, as you can see image1 and image2 have different dimensions and ratio. As you can see i'm doing something wrong the padding isn't working out just right. I'm setting **"item"** height to 0 because padding-bottom will end up taking care of the height. thoughts?

```js
var tags = document.getElementsByClassName('item');

for (var i = 0; i < tags.length; ++i) {
  /* This is the part I mentioned about, you may want to use one of the methods above depending on how your css and the rest of your code looks like*/
  tags[i].style.paddingBottom = (100 * (tags[i].offsetHeight / tags[i].offsetWidth)) + 'px';
}
```

```css
.item {
  position: relative;
  height: 0;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid red;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="item-box fashion">
  <a href="http://lorempixel.com/output/city-h-c-600-900-7.jpg" data-size="600x900" class="item">
    <img width="300" height="450" class="lazyload" alt="Image description" src="http://lorempixel.com/output/city-h-c-600-900-7.jpg" data-sizes="auto" />
  </a>
</div>

<div class="item-box fashion">
  <a href="http://lorempixel.com/output/fashion-q-c-600-400-5.jpg" data-size="600x900" class="item">
    <img width="300" height="200" class="lazyload" alt="Image description" src="http://lorempixel.com/output/fashion-q-c-600-400-5.jpg" data-sizes="auto" />
  </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all why don't you have to define the dimension of the picture. You can use element.offsetWidth element.offsetHeight OR element.style.width, element.style.height (these two would have to be parsed because they return a string for instance 5px) OR element.getBoundingClientRect() (the lattest is an object containing top, left, right, bottom etc.)
Now, that being said using java you can do the following ...

```js
var tags = document.getElementsByClassName('item');
    
    for(var i = 0; i < tags.length; ++i){
    /* This is the part I mentioned about, you may want to use one of the methods above depending on how your css and the rest of your code looks like*/
    tags[i].style.paddingBottom = (100 * (tags[i].offsetHeight / tags[i].offsetWidth)) + 'px';
    }
```

```css
.item{
  width: auto;
  height: auto;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="item-box fashion">
  <a href="http://lorempixel.com/output/city-h-c-600-900-7.jpg" data-size="600x900" class="item">
    <img width="300" height="450" class="lazyload" alt="Image description" src="http://lorempixel.com/output/city-h-c-600-900-7.jpg" data-sizes="auto" />
  </a>
</div>

<div class="item-box fashion">
  <a href="http://lorempixel.com/output/fashion-q-c-600-400-5.jpg" data-size="600x900" class="item">
    <img width="300" height="200" class="lazyload" alt="Image description" src="http://lorempixel.com/output/fashion-q-c-600-400-5.jpg" data-sizes="auto" />
  </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Appreciate your quick reply. Can you help me put this in context a little more. Where would I use element.offsetWidth element.offsetHeight in the first place? would I have to define their values 600px and 900px respectively?

Comment: I just showed you in the code I provided. If what you mean is how you use it to set your values, you don't. This is a read-only property. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/offsetHeight

Comment: I have edited the snippets that should give you a pretty good idea of what's going on

Comment: Perfect man! I understand a lot better now. The only thing is every image has different dimensions and they're all under the class "item." For example in your snippet if the second image were to have the dimensions width: 200 height: 400, how would that work?

Comment: Ok, I can't be doing that work for you I gave you the basics and that should be more than enough to make it work yourself. This is the second post I gave you and I haven't seen you trying anything. The policy here it is that you try something and I help you fix it or point you in the right direction. show me some work read the link that I give you and we will work it out

Comment: No worries man, I appreciate your help. I've been trying to get it to work to no avail, I feel I'm close just needs a little tweaking. I've included a snippet with what I have so far cheers.

Comment: You don't have to do anything. The code should work for any image! The width and height I specified was just to illustrate and to normalize all pictures' dimensions. If you want pictures to have different sizes just remove the dimensions I put and that should do it

Comment: I just saw your snippet and does not work. That's because your images are on your desktop. Second, as I mentioned you dont have to do anything else on the code it should work!

Comment: no my images aren't on my desktop, you can see they're where they're pointed href="http://lorempixel.com/output/city-h-c-600-900-7.jpg"

Comment: Ok, well I don't get what you need it seems to work when I add the code I posted! What exactly is the problem and what exactly do you neeed!

Comment: That should do it. You need to lok at how display property works on html!